# Unable to post Object type message to Messaging Queue(ActiveMQ) in Mule 4

Tags: jms, mule, mule-component, mule-esb

I am working on Mule migration from 3.9 to 4.1.4, trying to post ArrayList converted to JSON then posting to JMS queue (Using ActiveMQ), getting below error message

**Code:**

```
<sub-flow name="xxxx_part_data_to_messaging_system_flow">
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="0607190d-f3ed-4b1b-a5b4-3572c08cf2d5" message='[vars.correlationId ++ "" ++ vars.batch_id]'/>
    <jms:publish doc:name="xxxx-part-data-jms-queue" doc:id="b44b1880-7374-4e4d-a0e0-1b4ab193ade4" config-ref="transactional_data_jms_connection_config" destination="${ld.transaction.xxxx.part.messaging.queue}">
    <jms:message >
    <jms:body ><![CDATA[#[[payload]]]]></jms:body>
    </jms:message>
    </jms:publish>
    <logger message="#[" $(vars.correlationId)-$(vars.batch_id) xxxx part posted successfully into transaction data queue ${ld.transaction.xxxx.part.messaging.queue}"]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
</sub-flow>
```

**Error:**

```
the data fetched from DB is ArrayList
An error occurred while sending a message to the QUEUE: [ld.stock.part.queue]: 
Invalid type passed to StreamMessage: java.util.ArrayList . Allowed types are: 
Boolean, Byte, Short, Character, Integer, Long, Float, Double,String and 
byte[]. Invalid type passed to StreamMessage: java.util.ArrayList . Allowed 
types are: Boolean, Byte, Short, Character, Integer, Long, Float, Double,String 
and byte[].
Error type    : JMS:ILLEGAL_BODY
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your payload is not JSON. You are wrapping payload in an array with the extra []: `#[[payload]]` which will default to application/java.

You can transform to JSON inline. If you want the surrounding array use:

```
#[output application/json --- [payload]]
```

Or if you don't need that extra array use:

```
#[output application/json --- payload]
```

Inline example:

```
 <jms:publish doc:name="xxxx-part-data-jms-queue" doc:id="b44b1880-7374-4e4d-a0e0-1b4ab193ade4" config-ref="transactional_data_jms_connection_config" destination="${ld.transaction.xxxx.part.messaging.queue}">
    <jms:message >
       <jms:body ><![CDATA[#[[output application/json --- payload]]]]></jms:body>
    </jms:message>
 </jms:publish>
```